# How to use Android Studio without wifi?

Tags: android

I'm trying to develop Android application by using Android Studio and I'm just a beginner level.

The problem is that where I'm living has bad connection so I can't connect the internet every time but Android Studio always keep downloading something from the internet whenever I use.

Is there any possible way to develop an App by using Android Studio without wifi connection? I'd like to download every basic thing on my computer and don't let my Android Studio download something through the internet.

I really appreciate if you let me know how to deal with it.

Thanks :)

Comment: Just download the entire Internet to your computer!

Comment: "Android Studio always keep downloading something from the internet whenever I use" --> please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio does not need permanent Internetconection to run.

So, maybe you messed up something during the installation.

After instalalling the programm you just need to download the SDK packages you need like build and platform tools for the api version you are going to use.

Maybe you accidently checkt all APIs to download ... wich is a huge amount of data, and still background-downloading it.

Open Android SDK-Manager and look what you have marked to download.

If you have marked all ... decide wich one you need, uncheck the rest